# Displaying nested JSON array via jquery

Tags: jquery

Trying to use jquery to display json data from a nested array via getJSON, any advice would be much appreciated

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.getJSON('https://duunitori.fi/api/v1/jobentries?search=putkimies&format=json',
   function(data) {
     var results = data.results.slice(0, 0);
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
      $('.putkimies-positions').append('<p>' + data.results  + '</p>');
    });
  });
});
```

JSON file

```
{
 "count" : 8,
 "next": null,
 "previous": null,
 "results": [
    {
      "heading": "somehting",
      "date_posted": "2019-04-30T14:32:06.133561+03:00",
      "municipality_name": "somewhere",
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Please add the expected output to your question for clearer understanding.

Comment: and your question is ?

Comment: avoid using append at it  costs time,try to  store it in a string and render it as a whole

Comment: Hello sorry for the misunderstanding, new to stackoverflow. I want to display the results array from the json file, however, with the supplied code all that is displaying is [object, Object].

Comment: To find a good answer for you, add the target json object to your code snippet. Without any json example we only can just guess.

Comment: Please add sample expected output JSON for more clarification

Comment: Hello, added the json, i'm trying to display the results array

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over the results property (`data.results`) of your response object, each item in that array is a object as well so you need to get the properties `val.heading`,`val.date_posted`, `val.municipality_name`, etc

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.getJSON('https://duunitori.fi/api/v1/jobentries?search=putkimies&format=json',
   function(data) {
    $.each(data.results, function(key, val) {
      $('.putkimies-positions').append('<p>' + val.heading  + '</p>');
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="putkimies-positions"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that's exactly what I was after.

Comment: glad to have helped

Answer (score 0):

```js
var html = "";
$.getJSON('https://duunitori.fi/api/v1/jobentries?search=putkimies&format=json',
  function (data) {
    $.each(data.results, function (index, item) {
      html += "<ul>" + index;
      html += "<li><ul> Heading:- " + item.heading + "</ul></li>";
      html += "<li><ul> Company name:-" + item.company_name + "</ul></li>";
      html += "<li><ul> Slug:- " + item.slug + "</ul></li>";
      html += "</ul>";
    });
    $(".putkimies-positions").append(html);
  });
```

```css
ul { list-style-type: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='putkimies-positions'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just update your code with few script updates. Try this i hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON('https://duunitori.fi/api/v1/jobentries?    search=putkimies&format=json',
   function(data) {
    $.each(data.results, function(key, val) {
      $('.putkimies-positions').append(
        '<li><label>Heading: ' + val.heading  + '</label>' +
        '<span>Municipality Name: ' + val.municipality_name + '</span>' +
        '<small>Date: ' + val.date_posted + '</small></li>'
      );
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.putkimies-positions {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.putkimies-positions li + li {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.putkimies-positions li label,
.putkimies-positions li span, 
.putkimies-positions li small {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="putkimies-positions"></ul>
```